# How to do double nested aggregation in Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have such data structure:

```
class SearchItem
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }   
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double SalePrice { get; set; }   
    public IList<SearchFilter> Filters { get; set; }      
}
class SearchFilter
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see here `Filters` is a `nested array`. Example of `Filters` data:

```
Color: Red,
Size: Medium,
Material: N/A
```

So, other items can have same group names and attribute values.

Result that I try to get:

```
Color
  --Red(18)
  --Yellow(5) 
Size
  --Medium(20)
  --Large(5)
```

This is my mapping:

```
i.Mappings(m =>
               m.Map<SearchItem>(map =>
                   map.AutoMap().Properties(p =>
                       p.Text(s => s.Name(n => n.Description).Analyzer("snowball"))
                       .Nested<SearchFilter>(
                       n=>n.Name(nn=>nn.Filters)
                           .Properties(pr => pr
                               .Text(t => t.Name(nn => nn.Attribute))
                               .Text(t => t.Name(nn => nn.Group)))
                       )    
                       ))));
```

This is my query:

```
var result = _elasticClient.Search<SearchItem>(x =>
                x.Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(ff => ff.Sequence)).Size(48)
                    .Query(q => q.Bool(b =>
                    b.Must(ConstructBaseQuery(search))))
                    .Aggregations(a => a                            
                       .Nested("filters", n => n
                          .Path(p => p.Filters)
                          .Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("groups", t => t.Field(f => f.Filters.Suffix("Group"))
                              .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                                  .Terms("attribute", tt => tt.Field(ff => ff.Filters.Suffix("Attribute"))))
                              )))));
```

The problem is that the query don't do aggregation. Event if I do single aggregation like so:

```
var result = _elasticClient.Search<SearchItem>(x =>
                    x.Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(ff => ff.Sequence)).Size(48)
                        .Query(q => q.Bool(b =>
                        b.Must(ConstructBaseQuery(search))))
                        .Aggregations(a => a                            
                           .Nested("filters", n => n
                              .Path(p => p.Filters)
                              .Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("groups", t => t.Field(f => f.Filters.Suffix("Group")))))));
```

This is original query:

```
{
  "size": 48,
  "sort": [
    {
      "sequence": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "filters": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "filters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "groups": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "filters.Group"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "modern tables",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing works. So, I have two questions:

1. How can I do such aggregation using C# NEST?
2. I want to set nested fields (`Group` and `Attribute`) as `not_analyzed` but didn't find way to do this.

Comment: Could you add your edit as an answer and accept it? It'll help others see it as an answer in future. NEST by default camel cases properties names when serializing and sending to Elasticsearch; this behaviour can be controlled with `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` on `ConnectionSettings`

Comment: Done. Thanks, Russ, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of reading documentation for `Elastic 5.0` I found the answers:

1) It's important to put **lowercase** for nested properties. So mistake was here: `"field": "filters.Group"`. Should be `"filters.group"`

2) In Elastic 5.0 we haven't `not_anylyzed` index. Elastic team removed `String` type and add two new types instead (Text and Keyword). For text type aggregation is disabled by default and if you wanna enable it you should set `FieldData = true`. And we should use `keyword type` if don't wanna `analyze` property. So, my working index is:

```
 i.Mappings(m =>
                   m.Map<SearchItem>(map =>
                       map.AutoMap().Properties(p =>
                           p.Text(s => s.Name(n => n.Description).Analyzer("snowball"))
                           .Nested<SearchFilter>(
                           n=>n.Name(nn=>nn.Filters)
                               .Properties(pr => pr
                                   .Keyword(t => t.Name(nn => nn.Attribute))
                                   .Keyword(t => t.Name(nn => nn.Group)))
                           )    
                           ))));
```

And if anyone will stuck with processing response:

```
 class FilterGroup
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<FilterAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<FilterGroup> CreateList(ISearchResponse<SearchItem> result)
    {
        return result.Aggs.Nested("filters").Terms("groups").Buckets.Select(g => new FilterGroup()
        {
            Name = g.Key,
            Attributes = g.Terms("attributes").Buckets.Select(x => new FilterAttribute()
                {
                    Count = (int)x.DocCount,
                    Name = x.Key
                }).ToList()
        });           
    }
}

class FilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for next divers.